# Unity 3d - Explosion Area Damage

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've developed an airplane 3D shooter game. In this game, I want to make my plane shot a bomb. When the bomb gets to the enemies it will explode and give damage in the area of explosion.

I have already searched for a tutorial to make this code and the animation of explosion. But I couldn't find it. Please tell me about something that could solve this problem. I'm developing my game using C#.

Comment: Why don't you post what you have so far? Or are you starting from scratch and wondering how to begin?

Answer (score 0):

For the explosion animation, you could use a particle system. There are many pre-made ones in the Asset Store, such as this one: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/42285

For detecting what is affected in the explosion's area of effect, do a SphereCast (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) from the point of impact and then do whatever you want with any of the objects touched by the sphere.